# Unobstrusive javascript for Forgot Password Link

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I have a spring form that is used to log in to the website. Its a simple spring form with a username and password fields and a submit button. There is a forgot password link next to the submit button, which uses href="javascript:jump();" function as below:

```
function jump() {
    document.forms[0].action='pwdSelfResetStep1.mobi';
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

this works perfectly when the browser has javascript enabled. However, i want to use it on the browsers where javascript is disabled as well. (unobstrusive JS). Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: what's your forms method? POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the reason you submit the form is to get the user's email address, so you won't be able to do that (dynamically) without javascript, but you can simply change the href on the link to "pwdSelfResetStep1.mobi" instead, and attach jump() to the `onclick` event of the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: This is actually how you should do it in general; an `href` should point to a web page, and then the `onclick` should do the fancy stuff and cancel the normal click behavior by returning `false`. Your JavaScript can even read in the `href` from the `anchor` itself, to prevent duplication.

Comment: yes, I got the idea. I have used it in the exactly same way now. I am providing the minimum functionality by the href link and then providing enhanced functionality by JS. Thanks a lot!